# Calling a Web Service in a JSP

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jsp, struts

I am new to calling a REST service in a JSP. I have a form which goes through a struts2 action. I have a javascript function which performs a basic email validation. So instead of performing this validation using JavaScript I need to call a service which does email validation.

Do I need to call the validation service directly in JSP page if not then how can I achieve this.

```
<form name="resendEsignatureFormId" id="resendEsignatureFormId" action="<integration:urlAction actionName='/integration/resendEsignatureIntegration'></integration:urlAction>" 
    method="POST">
</form>
```

JavaScript function

```
function validate() {   
    // Need to call validation service here
    document.getElementById('resendEsignatureFormId').submit();
}

<table width=100%>
    <tr><td class="esignNavigation">            
       <a href="#x" onclick ="validate()"><span>Confirm</span></a>
       <a href="#x" onclick="hideSigners()"><span>Cancel</span></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you *need* to? No, but you may *want* to--assuming it is accessible from the client (e.g., allow access control etc.) *How* to do that is basic JS for which countless resources are available. You'll also need to handle failed validation, e.g., you need to prevent the default event, then do the actual submit only with validation success. There are any number of ways that can be handled. If you don't have any other real JS on the page and no other "real-time" validation you may want to do the validation on the back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP is a java server-side technology to generate HTML on the server.  A javascript call to a REST api is a browser -> server operation.  So you don't call a REST service in a JSP, you call a REST service from javascript.  That javascript can be invoked by an HTML event (onclick, etc.), and that HTML event may be described in a JSP - regardless of wether or not that event is dynamically generated by the JSP or just hard-coded.

You don't explicitly state that you have a server-side endpoint exposed to perform the email validation - you would need that as well.

Comment: So, I will be calling it somehow inside the JavaScript function propably by getting the form.

Comment: the javascript function will have to pass the current value of the email field as filled in on the form up to the server, so you will need to reference that element either via it's form and form element name, or you could just access it by a unique element id and the form doesn't matter.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Jim.

Comment: No problem - you may not be migrating from a JSP application to a rest-api and single page application architecture, but the sort of things you are wondering about come up when performing that type of migration.  This article might frame some of the issues for you:  https://spring.io/blog/2015/08/19/migrating-a-spring-web-mvc-application-from-jsp-to-angularjs.